# Is there any previous study on the relationship between convexity and the order of points in the general position?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Let's assume $V =(v_1,v_2,v_3,… ,v_n)$  is a set points in a general-position. For each point $v_i$, let's list the points in the order we encounter as we rotate around a certain direction (say clockwise)  and name this ordered set as

$$R_i = (v_{i_1},v_{i_2},v_{i_3},… ,v_{i_{n-1}})$$

For example, in the figure below, $R_1=(2,6,4,3,5)$

[Sample Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtxyK.jpg)

Let our polygon $C$ has $k$ vertices and defined like  $C = (v_1,v_2,v_3,… ,v_k)$.  It is easy to observe that all rotation sets ( or vectors)  $R_{v_1},R_{v_2},...R_{v_k}$ contains exact subsequence $v_1,v_2,...v_k$ if and only if $C$ is convex.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The thing which is studied a lot is to record the chirotope of the $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is the data, for each triple $pqr$, of whether the triangle $pqr$ is oriented clockwise, counterclockwise or (in the degenerate case) if the three points lie on a line. Fixing $p$, this is equivalent recording the circular order around $p$ of the $2(n-1)$ rays both from $p$ towards $q$ and from $p$ away from $q$. See Knuth's "Axioms and Hulls" https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-55611-7_1 . I don't know anyone who has studied just taking the rays from $p$ toward $q$ and not the others.

Comment: What you are describing is known as the [gift-wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) for finding the convex hull.

Comment: What I have observed in the meanwhile is that variation of Erdos-Szkeres theorem
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/subseq4proofs.pdf
can be applied on the rotation vectors. Assume that, for any two randomly chosen $v_i,v_j$  and corresponding vectors $R_{v_1},R_{v_2}$.  We should have a common subsequence of at least $\sqrt{n}+2$  length for sufficiently large $n$ in these vectors. It is obvious that you can arrange any two columns in completely reverse order, but common subsequences become inevitable after considering any other columns.